# SSIS Error: "Metadata could not be determined because procedure uses temp table"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssis

We have recently restored SSIS Packages and I'm facing this error whenever I try to execute a SSIS package:
Unable to determine metadata because « INSERT INTO #File_Results EXEC Master.dbo.xp_fileexists @filepath »
in procedure «DDLRevisionHistory» uses temporary table

DDLRevisionHistory is a trigger that controls our internal file versioning. If I disable the trigger SSIS packages are executed with no problems.

```
CREATE TABLE #File_Results(
        File_Exists int,
        File_is_a_Directory int,
        Parent_Directory_Exists int
    )
    INSERT INTO #File_Results
    EXEC Master.dbo.xp_fileexist @filepath;
```

This is the part of the code that is throwing the error. Searching forums I've tried other solutions like using FMTONLY (which I believe is deprecated), adding

```
WITH RESULT SETS
```

but I couldn't make it work (maybe I'm using it wrong?) or instead of using temporal tables using global temporal tables.

Thanks for the help

Comment: "*but I couldn't make it work*" - What does this mean?...did you get an error?...what did that error say? You should also include the full trigger definition for `DDLRevisionHistory`.